# change the url using with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i am trying to change the url using htaccess rewrite 
i want to change this url

```
page/details.php?name=abcdef&id=18
```

to

```
page/abcdef
```

Here my sample code for this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^company/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$1 company/details.php?name=$1&id=$2 [R=301,L]
```

this is not working, and also i was tried many code but not working,please help me to find htaccess code for this url
Thanks advance

Comment: did my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're after:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*name=([a-zA-Z0-9]*).*$
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)&id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /page/%1? [R=301,L]
```

This will check for these 2 parameters in the query string.